# Using external js file in angular 6 component

Tags: javascript, angular, import, angular6

I am trying to use a js file into my angular 6 application. Steps I followed are as follows:

**1. Created `testfile.js` file:**

> ```
> var testa = function () {
>    function testMethod() {
>         console.log('hello');
>     }
> }
> var testmodule = new testa();
> module.exports = testmodule;
> ```

**2. In `angular.cli.json`. For testing purpose tesfile.js is at the same location as `angular.cli.json` is:**

> ```
>  "scripts": [
>               "testfile.js"
>             ],
> ```

**3. In typings.d.ts file, declared it:**

> `declare var testmodule: any;`

**4. In ts file, tried to use it as:**

> ```
>  public ngOnInit() {
>         testmodule.testMethod()
>     }
> ```

But when angular component is used, warning in console is:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: testmodule is not defined
```

I tried another alternative, like importing js file inside .ts file as:

1. `import * as mymodule '../../testfile.js'`
2. `"allowJs":  true`
   but this is also not identifying testmodule or testfile.

What wrong am I doing here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I made a demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/4jw6rk1j1x , like so:

`testfile.js`

```js
function testa() {}
testa.prototype.testMethod = function testMethod() {
  console.log("hello");
};
var testmodule = new testa();

export { testmodule };
```

And in the `main.ts`

```js
import { enableProdMode } from "@angular/core";
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic";

import { AppModule } from "./app/app.module";
import { environment } from "./environments/environment";

import { testmodule } from "./testfile";

testmodule.testMethod();

if (environment.production) {
  enableProdMode();
}

platformBrowserDynamic()
  .bootstrapModule(AppModule)
  .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

You can see on the console tab the 'hello' text

Note that I made some changes in the `testfile.js`

Comment: Yes, it was typo.

Comment: I tried both export default and export { }, but same issue.

Comment: @sdeep I made a demo, don't know if it is what you need

Comment: Great!! it worked. But didn't get why setting the function into prototype worked.

Comment: @sdeep There you go [Object.prototype.constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/constructor#Changing_the_constructor_of_a_function), I follow this instruction

Answer (score 1):

Give Reference to your scripts inside the angular-cli.json file.

```
"scripts": [
    "../path_of_script" 
 ];
```

then add in typings.d.ts

```
declare var testModule : any;
```

Import it where you want to use it

```
import * as myModule from 'testModule';
```

Answer (score 1):

You can import your external JS in **angular.json**

> ```
> "scripts": [
>               "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
>               "node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js",
>               "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js",
>               "../../../assets/js/counter"
>             ]
> ```

If you want to import JS file for the specific html component then you can **import** your js file in your **yourComponent.ts**

**Just Like:**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import "../../../assets/js/counter";
```

You can see here I have imported **counter.js** in the specific HTML page.

In this line "**../../../assets/js/counter**" **counter** is a js file name. You have no need to add **.js** after the file name.

Please make sure you set your path carefully **../../..**

You can store your all external js files in **assets/js** folder. And then you can import your specific js file in specific component.ts.

This is working perfectly for me in angular 6.